# Marcar Check anterior (Pai) ao nó

Tags: c#, jquery, html5

O que eu preciso é que quando for selecionado O Item "Bola" que é um nó filho do check "1031-CALOTA ...", o nó Pai seja selecionado também.
Ou
Não deixar selecionar o nó filho se o nó pai não estiver selecionado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>

    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Peça</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Lista.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (ViewBag.Lista[i].TemPeca > 0)
                {
                <td>
                    @if (ViewBag.Lista[i].ACHOU == "N")
                    {
                        <input type="text" name="optionsObsPeca[]" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Obs" autocomplete="off" />
                        <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="id[]" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" checked />


      @ViewBag.Lista[i].Descricao
                    }
                    else // ITENS
                    {
                        <p>
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;
                            <input type="checkbox" name="optionsItens[]" att="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].IdItem" />
                            @ViewBag.Lista[i].DescricaoItem
                        </p>
                    }

                </td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>
                        @if (ViewBag.lista[i].ACHOU == "N")
                        {
                            <input type="text" name="optionsObsPeca[]" value="" autocomplete="off" />
                            <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="id[]" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" />
                            @ViewBag.Lista[i].Descricao
                        }
                        else // ITENS
                        {
                            <p>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                                <input type="checkbox" name="optionsItens[]" att="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].IdItem"  />
                                @ViewBag.Lista[i].DescricaoItem
                            </p>
                        }
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>

            cont++;
        }
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buscando o checkbox que está na mesma célula pelo `name`, usando `.closest` e `.find()` você consegue marcar, porém não faz sentido esses id's com colchetes, até porque você os está repetindo, o que é incorreto.

Código:

```
$('[name="optionsItens[]"]').on("change", function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this)
      .closest("td")
      .find('[name="options[]"]')
      .prop("checked", true);
   }
});
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
$('[name="optionsItens[]"]').on("change", function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
      $(this)
      .closest("td")
      .find('[name="options[]"]')
      .prop("checked", true);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-bordered">
<thead>

<tr>
  <th scope="col">Peça</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

      <tr>
          <td>
                  <input type="text" name="optionsObsPeca[]" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Obs" autocomplete="off" />
                  <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="id[]" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" />
                  <p>
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  &nbsp;
                      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsItens[]" att="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].IdItem" />
                      @ViewBag.Lista[i].DescricaoItem
                  </p>

          </td>
              <td>
                      <input type="text" name="optionsObsPeca[]" value="" autocomplete="off" />
                      <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="id[]" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" />
                      <p>
                          &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                          &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;
                          <input type="checkbox" name="optionsItens[]" att="@ViewBag.Lista[i].Id" value="@ViewBag.Lista[i].IdItem"  />
                          @ViewBag.Lista[i].DescricaoItem
                      </p>
              </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigada, os Id[] realmente estão sem nada, foram apenas tentativas sem sucessos ...

Answer (score 4):

Seguindo na sua estrutura você pode fazer algo tipo o exemplo abaixo. Assim a opção principal ao ser clicada interage com todos os seu filhos e se não haver nenhum filho selecionado a principal será desmarcada também.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  $('input[name="options[]"]').click(function() {
    let pai = $(this).parents('td');
    $(pai)
      .children('p')
      .children('input[type="checkbox"]')
      .prop("checked", $(this).prop('checked'));
  });

  $('input[name="itemOptions[]"]').click(function() {

    let pai = $(this).parents('td');
    let itensMarcados = $(pai)
      .children('p')
      .children('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
      .length;

    pai.children('input[name="options[]"]')
      .prop("checked", itensMarcados > 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="opcao a"> Frutas
      <p>
        &emsp;<input type="checkbox" name="itemOptions[]" value="">  Melão
        <br> &emsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="itemOptions[]" value="">  Melância
        <br> &emsp;
        <input type="checkbox" name="itemOptions[]" value="">  Laranja
        <br>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```